# PHP submit form data and email

Tags: php, html, forms

I have this site with form data that needs to be input, originally was going to have export and then let the user email but i always go overboard and now this is what i have, I want this form data to submit a file and email the submitted file. I get a file missing error, i am using Mamp to for server testing. thanks for any help, been reading this site for years but finally getting to use it.
I have some tidy up to do but wasnt sure what all you needed. Upon clicking the submit button, a page opens with "file not found" error.
Here is the site data:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>MID Inspection Form</title>

   <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
   <style>
    body {background-image: url(images/bg3.png);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-color: #cddbe7;




       }
    </style>


    <script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("form1");
    x.disabled = true;
}
</script>



    <script src="js/gen_validatorv31.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        <script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker({
      language: 'en',
      pick12HourFormat: true
    });
  });
</script>


<form method="post" name="`enter code here`Inspection Form" action="php-form-action.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<head>    
</head>

<body>
<?php
if(!empty($errors))
{
    echo nl2br($errors);
}
?>


<h3>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>

<p>
    <input type="reset" name="reset" id="reset" value="Reset Form">
    Attach Inspector's Report!
    <input type="file" id="form1" multiple placeholder="Attach Report">
    <input type="submit" Submit>
    <!--<input type="button" onclick="tableToExcel('midTable', 'MID inspection table')" value="Export to Excel">-->
    <!-- export to excel option to be added -->
</p>
    </h3>
<div class="date col-md-6 col-xs-6 col-lg-4">  
    <p>
    <label for="date" class="col-lg-1 control-label">Inspection Date:  </label>
    <label><input type="date" name="date" required title="(required)"></label>


    Location 
    <select class="form-control styled-select" name="location" id="location" required title="(required)">
      <option value="">--select--</option>
      <option value="SG 440">Abbeville, SC</option>
      <option value="SVC851">Agrock, FL</option>
      <option value="BG 130">Akron, OH</option>
      <option value="QCP  7">Albany Port, NY</option>
      <option value="PLE 19">Aliquippa, PA</option>
      <option value="S    5">Ampthill, VA</option>
      <option value="QC 178">Amsterdam, NY</option>
      <option value="SH 365">Andrews, SC</option>
      <option value="BAA 10">Annapolis Jct, MD</option>
      <option value="QRX  9">Apiny, NJ </option>
      <option value="0BA279">Ardmore, AL </option>
      <option value="BED 13">Armco Junction, OH</option>
      <option value="CA 520">Ashland, KY</option>
      <option value="QD 127">Ashtabula, OH</option>
      <option value="000294">Athens, AL </option>
      <option value="SG 506">Athens, GA</option>
      <option value="00H277">Atkinson, KY</option>
      <option value="YYG171">Atlanta Hulsey, GA </option>
      <option value="ANB865">Atlanta, GA</option>
      <option value="QN   0">Attleboro, MA</option>
      <option value="SX 820">Auburndale, FL</option>
      <option value="AK 459">Augusta, GA</option>
      <option value="00F375">Avalon St, TN</option>
      <option value="QS   9">Avon, IN</option>
      <option value="AN 588">BRUNSWICK JCT CP GA</option>
      <option value="S  653">Baldwin, FL</option>
      <option value="BAK 88">Balt Bay View, MD</option>
      <option value="BAO  8">Balt Curtis Bay, MD</option>
      <option value="BAM  3">Balt Locust Point, MD</option>
      <option value="BAL  5">Balt Penn Mary Exim, MD</option>
      <option value="BAL  3">Balt Sparrows Point, MD</option>
      <option value="BAA  3">Balt West Baltimore, MD </option>
      <option value="BAA  1">Baltimore, MD</option>
      <option value="A  111">BattleBoro, NC</option>
      <option value="QRR  6">Bayonne, NJ</option>
      <option value="QRC 11">Bayway, NJ</option>
      <option value="QM 226">Beauharnois, PQ</option>
      <option value="000ZA3">Bedford Park, IL</option>
      <option value="QC 296">Belle Isle, NY</option>
      <option value="S    9">Bellwood, VA</option>
      <option value="BAK 51">Belvedere, MD</option>
      <option value="QL 134">Benning, DC </option>
      <option value="CG  86">Benton Harbor, MI</option>
      <option value="BN   5">Benwood, WV</option>
      <option value="0LB405">Bessemer, AL</option>
      <option value="AZA890">Big Bend, FL</option>
      <option value="000007">Big Ditch CP, KY</option>
      <option value="CA 514">Big Sandy JCT, KY</option>
      <option value="000389">Birmingham, AL</option>
      <option value="SO 631">Blount Island, FL</option>
      <option value="Z  245">Bostic Yard, NC </option>
      <option value="SF 404">Bostic, NC</option>
      <option value="QB   5">Boston Beacon Park, MA</option>
      <option value="000388">Boyles, AL</option>
      <option value="AZA916">Bradenton, FL</option>
      <option value="QNB  0">Braintree, MA</option>
      <option value="Z  259">Brice, NC</option>
      <option value="00J123">Bridgeport, AL </option>
      <option value="QRZ  1">Brills, NJ</option>
      <option value="BN  38">Brooklyn Jct, WV</option>
      <option value="00F319">Brownsville, TN </option>
      <option value="000N95">Bruceton, TN </option>
      <option value="BA  76">Brunswick, MD</option>
      <option value="QD   6">Buffalo ICTF, NY</option>
      <option value="QDN 10">Buffalo Kenmore YD, NY</option>
      <option value="QDA  3">Buffalo Ohio Street, NY</option>
      <option value="QC 434">Buffalo, NY</option>
      <option value="S  626">Busch, FL</option>
      <option value="000426">Calera, AL</option>
      <option value="00J210">Calhoun, GA</option>
      <option value="00J240">Cartersville, GA</option>
      <option value="00H235">Casky Yard, KY</option>
      <option value="QR 110">Catskill, NY</option>
      <option value="S  362">Cayce, SC</option>
      <option value="0ZA141">Cayuga, IN </option>
      <option value="QM 214">Cecile, PQ</option>
      <option value="QVR  3">Cedar Hill, CT</option>
      <option value="SG 631">Cedartown, GA</option>
      <option value="SX 833">Central Florida ILC, FL</option>
      <option value="QJ  17">Chalk Point, MD</option>
      <option value="BAV 21">Chambersburg, PA </option>
      <option value="A  390">Charleston, SC</option>
      <option value="CA 454">Charleston, WV</option>
      <option value="SF 330">Charlotte, NC</option>
      <option value="CA 181">Charlottesville, VA</option>
      <option value="CEA 18">Chatham, ON</option>
      <option value="00J152">Chattanooga, TN</option>
      <option value="QBG  6">Chelsea, MA </option>
      <option value="DCQ 25">Chicago 59th St, IL </option>
      <option value="DC  27">Chicago Clearing, IL</option>
      <option value="QFX  1">Chicago Global One, IL </option>
      <option value="DD   2">Chicago, IL</option>
      <option value="BB  98">Chillicothe, OH</option>
      <option value="DAL 32">Cicero, IL </option>
      <option value="00T110">Cincinnati TOFC, OH </option>
      <option value="0KC110">Cincinnati, OH</option>
      <option value="BA 303">Clarksburg, WV</option>

      </select>

    SPLC            
    <select class="form-control styled-select" name="location" id="location_1" required title="(required)">
      <option value="">--select--</option>
        <option value="111111"> </option>
      <!--add split code numbers here-->    
    </select>

   Arrival Time:
    <input type="time" name="time" placeholder="hrs:mins" pattern="^([0-1]?[0-9]|2[0-4]):([0-5][0-9])(:[0-5][0-9])?$" class="inputs time" > 


    Departure Time:         
    <input type="time" name="time" placeholder="hrs:mins" pattern="^([0-1]?[0-9]|2[0-4]):([0-5][0-9])(:[0-5][0-9])?$" class="inputs time" >
    </p>
</div>

<div class="Supervisor Name">  
    <p>
    <label for="division" class="col-lg-1 control-label">Supervisor Name: </label>
    <input id="LocationCity" type="text" value="" class="nobdrLtTopB1" placeholder="Supervisor Name" />
    ID Number:
    <input id="idnumber" type="text" value="" class="nobdrLtTopB1" placeholder="I.D. Number" />
    Phone Number:       
    <input id="phonenumber" type="text" value="" class="nobdrLtTopB1" placeholder="Phone Number" />
  </p>
    <p>MID Insp Name:
      <input id="midInspectorName" type="text" value="" class="nobdrLtTopB1" placeholder="MID Insp. Name" />
      Phone Number:         
      <input id="midphonenumber" type="text" value="" class="nobdrLtTopB1" placeholder="Phone Number" />
  </p>
</div>

<div>
 <div class="center"><ul>INSPECTION LOCATION</ul>

    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox4" id="checkbox4">
    <label for="checkbox4"><i>CAR SHOP</i> 
      <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox5" id="checkbox5">
      <i>TRANSPORTATION YARD</i> 
      <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox6" id="checkbox6">
      <i>PROGRAM SHOP</i>
    </label>

  </div>
</div>

<h5>
# OF Cars Inspected <select class="form-control styled-select" name="carsInspected" id="carsInspected" >
        <option value="">--select--</option>
        <option value="1">  1</option>
        <option value="2"> 2</option>
        <option value="3"> 3</option>
        <option value="4"> 4</option>
        <option value="5"> 5</option>
        <option value="6"> 6</option>
        <option value="7"> 7</option>
        <option value="8"> 8</option>
        <option value="9"> 9</option>
        <option value="10"> 10</option>
                    </select>

<p># OF Car Exceptions <select class="form-control styled-select" name="exceptions" id="exceptions" >
      <option value="">--select--</option>
    <option value="1">  1</option>
    <option value="2"> 2</option>
    <option value="3"> 3</option>
    <option value="4"> 4</option>
    <option value="5"> 5</option>
    <option value="6"> 6</option>
    <option value="7"> 7</option>
    <option value="8"> 8</option>
    <option value="9"> 9</option>
    <option value="10"> 10</option>
    </select>
  </p>

<p>&nbsp;</p></h5>
       <p>&nbsp;</p>

       <h4>
        <table width="1277" border="5" cellspacing="4" cellpadding="4">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th width="52" scope="col">LIST</th>
      <th width="1033" scope="col">DESCRIPTION OF DEFECT FINDINGS</th>
      <th width="112" scope="col">EXCECTION</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">1</th>
      <td height="37" colspan="1">
                        <input id="ComWHS_1" type="text" value="" class="nobdrLtTopBl" placeholder="Comment on deficiency:" style="width:100%;" name="ComWHS_02" title="Com WHS 02" />
        </td>
      <td align="center">
         <input type="checkbox" id="cb_e1" name="cb_shop"/>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">2</th>
      <td height="37" colspan="1">
                        <input id="ComWHS_2" type="text" value="" class="nobdrLtTopBl" placeholder="Comment on deficiency:" style="width:100%;" name="ComWHS_02" title="Com WHS 02" />
        </td>
      <td align="center">
         <input type="checkbox" id="cb_e2" name="cb_shop"/>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">3</th>
      <td height="37" colspan="1">
                        <input id="ComWHS_3" type="text" value="" class="nobdrLtTopBl" placeholder="Comment on deficiency:" style="width:100%;" name="ComWHS_02" title="Com WHS 02" />
        </td>
      <td align="center">
         <input type="checkbox" id="cb_e3" name="cb_shop"/>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">4</th>
      <td height="37" colspan="1">
                        <input id="ComWHS_4" type="text" value="" class="nobdrLtTopBl" placeholder="Comment on deficiency:" style="width:100%;" name="ComWHS_02" title="Com WHS 02" />
        </td>
      <td align="center">
         <input type="checkbox" id="cb_e4" name="cb_shop"/>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">5</th>
      <td height="37" colspan="1">
                        <input id="ComWHS_5" type="text" value="" class="nobdrLtTopBl" placeholder="Comment on deficiency:" style="width:100%;" name="ComWHS_02" title="Com WHS 02" />
        </td>
      <td align="center">
         <input type="checkbox" id="cb_e5" name="cb_shop"/>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">6</th>
      <td height="37" colspan="1">
                        <input id="ComWHS_6" type="text" value="" class="nobdrLtTopBl" placeholder="Comment on deficiency:" style="width:100%;" name="ComWHS_02" title="Com WHS 02" />
        </td>
      <td align="center">
         <input type="checkbox" id="cb_e6" name="cb_shop"/>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">7</th>
     <td height="37" colspan="1">
                        <input id="ComWHS_7" type="text" value="" class="nobdrLtTopBl" placeholder="Comment on deficiency:" style="width:100%;" name="ComWHS_02" title="Com WHS 02" />
        </td>
      <td align="center">
         <input type="checkbox" id="cb_e7" name="cb_shop"/>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">8</th>
      <td height="37" colspan="1">
                        <input id="ComWHS_8" type="text" value="" class="nobdrLtTopBl" placeholder="Comment on deficiency:" style="width:100%;" name="ComWHS_02" title="Com WHS 02" />
        </td>
      <td align="center">
         <input type="checkbox" id="cb_e8" name="cb_shop"/>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">9</th>
      <td height="37" colspan="1">
                        <input id="ComWHS_9" type="text" value="" class="nobdrLtTopBl" placeholder="Comment on deficiency:" style="width:100%;" name="ComWHS_02" title="Com WHS 02" />
        </td>
      <td align="center">
         <input type="checkbox" id="cb_e9" name="cb_shop"/>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">10</th>
      <td height="37" colspan="1">
                        <input id="ComWHS_10" type="text" value="" class="nobdrLtTopBl" placeholder="Comment on deficiency:" style="width:100%;" name="ComWHS_02" title="Com WHS 02" />
        </td>
      <td align="center">
         <input type="checkbox" id="cb_e10" name="cb_shop"/>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">11</th>
      <td height="37" colspan="1">
                        <input id="ComWHS_11" type="text" value="" class="nobdrLtTopBl" placeholder="Comment on deficiency:" style="width:100%;" name="ComWHS_02" title="Com WHS 02" />
        </td>
      <td align="center">
         <input type="checkbox" id="cb_e11" name="cb_shop"/>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">12</th>
      <td height="37" colspan="1">
                        <input id="ComWHS_12" type="text" value="" class="nobdrLtTopBl" placeholder="Comment on deficiency:" style="width:100%;" name="ComWHS_02" title="Com WHS 02" />
        </td>
      <td align="center">
         <input type="checkbox" id="cb_e12" name="cb_shop"/>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
  </h4>


<table width="1277" border="5" cellspacing="4" cellpadding="4">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th width="52" scope="col">LIST</th>
      <th width="1057" scope="col">PROVIDE ACTION PLAN FOR LISTED EXCEPTIONS ABOVE</th>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">1</th>
      <td height="37" colspan="1"><input id="Com1_" type="text" value="" class="nobdrLtTopBl" placeholder="Comment on deficiency:" style="width:100%;" name="ComWHS_" title="Com WHS 02" /></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">2</th>
      <td height="37" colspan="1"><input id="Com2_" type="text" value="" class="nobdrLtTopBl" placeholder="Comment on deficiency:" style="width:100%;" name="ComWHS_" title="Com WHS 02" /></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">3</th>
      <td height="37" colspan="1"><input id="Com3_" type="text" value="" class="nobdrLtTopBl" placeholder="Comment on deficiency:" style="width:100%;" name="ComWHS_" title="Com WHS 02" /></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">4</th>
      <td height="37" colspan="1"><input id="Com4_" type="text" value="" class="nobdrLtTopBl" placeholder="Comment on deficiency:" style="width:100%;" name="ComWHS_" title="Com WHS 02" /></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">5</th>
      <td height="37" colspan="1"><input id="Com5_" type="text" value="" class="nobdrLtTopBl" placeholder="Comment on deficiency:" style="width:100%;" name="ComWHS_" title="Com WHS 02" /></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">6</th>
      <td height="37" colspan="1"><input id="Com6_" type="text" value="" class="nobdrLtTopBl" placeholder="Comment on deficiency:" style="width:100%;" name="ComWHS_" title="Com WHS 02" /></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">7</th>
      <td height="37" colspan="1"><input id="Com7_" type="text" value="" class="nobdrLtTopBl" placeholder="Comment on deficiency:" style="width:100%;" name="ComWHS_" title="Com WHS 02" /></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">8</th>
      <td height="37" colspan="1"><input id="Com8_" type="text" value="" class="nobdrLtTopBl" placeholder="Comment on deficiency:" style="width:100%;" name="ComWHS_" title="Com WHS 02" /></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">9</th>
      <td height="37" colspan="1"><input id="Com9_" type="text" value="" class="nobdrLtTopBl" placeholder="Comment on deficiency:" style="width:100%;" name="ComWHS_" title="Com WHS 02" /></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">10</th>
      <td height="37" colspan="1"><input id="Com10_" type="text" value="" class="nobdrLtTopBl" placeholder="Comment on deficiency:" style="width:100%;" name="ComWHS_" title="Com WHS 02" /></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">11</th>
      <td height="37" colspan="1"><input id="Com11_" type="text" value="" class="nobdrLtTopBl" placeholder="Comment on deficiency:" style="width:100%;" name="ComWHS_" title="Com WHS 02" /></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">12</th>
      <td height="37" colspan="1"><input id="Com12_" type="text" value="" class="nobdrLtTopBl" placeholder="Comment on deficiency:" style="width:100%;" name="ComWHS_" title="Com WHS 02" /></td>

    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</form>

</html>

here is the php file

<?php 
// Pear library includes
// You should have the pear lib installed
include_once('Mail.php');
include_once('Mail_Mime/mime.php');

//Settings 
$max_allowed_file_size = 1100; // size in KB 
$allowed_extensions = array("jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "bmp");
$upload_folder = './uploads/'; //<-- this folder must be writeable by the script
$your_email = 'pasnthru99@gmail.com';//<<--  update this to your email address

$errors ='';

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    //Get the uploaded file information
    $name_of_uploaded_file =  basename($_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);

    //get the file extension of the file
    $type_of_uploaded_file = substr($name_of_uploaded_file, 
                            strrpos($name_of_uploaded_file, '.') + 1);

    $size_of_uploaded_file = $_FILES["uploaded_file"]["size"]/1024;

    ///------------Do Validations-------------
    if(empty($_POST['name'])||empty($_POST['email']))
    {
        $errors .= "\n Name and Email are required fields. ";   
    }
    if(IsInjected($visitor_email))
    {
        $errors .= "\n Bad email value!";
    }

    if($size_of_uploaded_file > $max_allowed_file_size ) 
    {
        $errors .= "\n Size of file should be less than $max_allowed_file_size";
    }

    //------ Validate the file extension -----
    $allowed_ext = false;
    for($i=0; $i<sizeof($allowed_extensions); $i++) 
    { 
        if(strcasecmp($allowed_extensions[$i],$type_of_uploaded_file) == 0)
        {
            $allowed_ext = true;        
        }
    }

    if(!$allowed_ext)
    {
        $errors .= "\n The uploaded file is not supported file type. ".
        " Only the following file types are supported: ".implode(',',$allowed_extensions);
    }

    //send the email 
    if(empty($errors))
    {
        //copy the temp. uploaded file to uploads folder
        $path_of_uploaded_file = $upload_folder . $name_of_uploaded_file;
        $tmp_path = $_FILES["uploaded_file"]["tmp_name"];

        if(is_uploaded_file($tmp_path))
        {
            if(!copy($tmp_path,$path_of_uploaded_file))
            {
                $errors .= '\n error while copying the uploaded file';
            }
        }

        //send the email
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $visitor_email = $_POST['email'];
        $user_message = $_POST['message'];
        $to = $your_email;
        $subject="New form submission";
        $from = $your_email;
        $text = "A user  $name has sent you this message:\n $user_message";

        $message = new Mail_mime(); 
        $message->setTXTBody($text); 
        $message->addAttachment($path_of_uploaded_file);
        $body = $message->get();
        $extraheaders = array("From"=>$from, "Subject"=>$subject,"Reply-To"=>$visitor_email);
        $headers = $message->headers($extraheaders);
        $mail = Mail::factory("mail");
        $mail->send($to, $headers, $body);
        //redirect to 'thank-you page
        header('Location: thank-you.html');
    }
}

function IsInjected($str)
{
  $injections = array('(\n+)',
              '(\r+)',
              '(\t+)',
              '(%0A+)',
              '(%0D+)',
              '(%08+)',
              '(%09+)'
              );
  $inject = join('|', $injections);
  $inject = "/$inject/i";
  if(preg_match($inject,$str))
    {
    return true;
  }
  else
    {
    return false;
  }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"> 
<html>
<head>
    <title>File upload form</title>
<!-- define some style elements-->
<style>
label,a, body 
{
    font-family : Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size : 12px; 
}

</style>    

<?php
if(!empty($errors))
{
    echo nl2br($errors);
}
?>
<form method="POST" name="email_form_with_php" 
action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: Does the file `php-form-action.php` exist? Are you submitting to a non-existent page? It's also quite unusual to put the `<form>` tag before the `<head>` and outside the `<body>`.

Comment: What @showdev commented, from your question this looks like a 404 file not found error (HTTP). Check that the new location (the one the browser requests in the form POST request) exists on your MAMP server. URL resolution rules are defined w/ detail in RFC 3986 https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-5

Comment: thanks for this, I have several more issues that I will need to resolve also, I appreciate the help and apologize for duplicate request, I searched and didn't find exactly what I was asking.